# Data Doesn't Load Unless UIButton Clicked

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api, uibutton, segue, grand-central-dispatch

This might be a strange case so I apologize in advance if my problem or solution is unclear:

I have a **LoginViewController** that fetches a users Facebook profile picture, username, email, etc. I then have it segue to a **HomeViewController** that displays some objects, other items, and a UIView that shows the users profile picture.

The *strange* part is that the UIImage that i create **only gets transferred** when I use a UIButton. I can not seem to get the image to be sent to the **HomeViewController** any other way. I even set up a GCP to have it try and wait in order for Facebook to deliver the information - still nothing. Below is the code that I have for the **LoginViewController.m**. If anyone has any idea on why this is happening I would be extremely grateful. thank you!

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


@interface LoginViewController ()

- (void)toggleHiddenState:(BOOL)shouldHide;

@end

@implementation LoginViewController

@synthesize profPicture;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self toggleHiddenState:YES];
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"";

    self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email"];
    self.loginButton.delegate = self;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void)toggleHiddenState:(BOOL)shouldHide{
    self.lblUsername.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.lblEmail.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.profilePicture.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.loggedinwallpaper.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.FBlogout.hidden = shouldHide;
}


-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView{
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"";

    [self toggleHiddenState:NO];
}

-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView{
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"";

    [self toggleHiddenState:YES];
}

-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user{
    NSLog(@"%@", user);
    self.profilePicture.profileID = user.objectID;
    self.lblUsername.text = user.name;
    self.lblEmail.text = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^(void){
        // Create Facebook Profile Picture from User ID url
        NSString *pic_link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?width=300&height=300", user.objectID];
        NSURL *pic_url = [NSURL URLWithString:pic_link];
        profPicture = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:pic_url]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            //Main Thread : UI Updates
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            UIViewController *homeViewController = (UIViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
            [self performSelector:@selector(prepareForSegue:sender:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0 ];
            [self presentViewController:homeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];


        });
    });
}

-(void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    HomeViewController *homeviewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    homeviewController.homepic = profPicture;
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you shared I'd assume that the button you mentioned worked because you wired that up in the Storyboard with a segue, right? (Dragged an arrow to the next VC?)

The issue with your code is that here

```
[self performSelector:@selector(prepareForSegue:sender:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0 ];
```

you are triggering `prepareForSegue:sender:` on your own without the necessary parameters - you don't have a segue to prepare for as you aren't even segueing to the other view controller. So when `HomeViewController *homeviewController = segue.destinationViewController;` is executed `segue` is nil so the image can't be set.

You should be able to fix this by replacing your code which runs on the main thread with this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    // Main Thread : UI Updates
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"<insert segue identifier here>" sender:self];
});
```

Make sure to set a name in your Storyboard for the segue between the view controllers and use that identifier here. (See the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:))

Comment: when i go back to using the gcd it shows the segue perform twice - like 2 clicks. I thought maybe I had been performing the segue somewhere else besides this but I am not. not really sure why its happening lol

Comment: Try placing a breakpoint in your code, maybe `loginViewFetchedUserInfo:user:` is called twice? Could you check your segues too? As far as I see Xcode is compiling fine when two segues have the same identifier (it's just showing a warning to me).

Comment: I got it to work now. I think the issue was just I was trying to have it do the same segue twice two different ways somewhere else - idk.. but it worked so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    HomeViewController *homeviewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    homeviewController.homepic = [UIImage alloc] init];
    homeviewController.homepic = profPicture;
}
```

Comment: for some reason doing this method shows the segue twice - as if the button is clicked 2 times. not sure if this is internal or something I am missing :\